# Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined, when trying to render a jade template

Tags: express, pug, rendering

The strangest thing. I'm passing a value to a Jade 'variable' and the template reads the variable, as you can see its printed to the console (see 'this is1...this is2 etc') and rendered on the screen. However, the page seems to be getting rendered a second time, at which point the template has lost the value of the variable -> see 'this is1' on the second occurance.

I cant understand why the page is rendering twice. Also, I say its strange as the page appears to renders as normal, it's only when I check the log I can see errors and when I then try to make a request based on one of the variables object IDs it is clear that the template thinks the values of (currentUser) the varables are undefined, Any thoughts? I've been pulling y hair out about this. Thanks:

ROUTE.js:

```
router.get('/setuser/:id',ctrlPages.setUser);
```

CONTROLLER.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
module.exports.setUser = (req, res) => {
 console.log('req param id', req.params.id);
 User.find({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, { new: true }, (err, u 
userId) => {
        console.log('userid',userId);
            if (userId === null) { 
            console.log('error');
            res.redirect('/');
            } 
        else{
        console.log('user set');
        //currentUser = userId;
        res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
};
```

TEMPLATE:

```
extends layout
include _includes/sharedHTMLfunctions
block content  
    .row.page-header
        .col-lg-8
            .row
                .col-xs-12.col-sm-6
                    .panel.panel-primary
                        .panel-heading
                            h2.panel-title Admin page
                        - console.log('this is3',currentUser)
                        .panel-body
                            .text-center
                                .jumbotron
                                    h4 This page is for managing users
                                    h4 You will be able to create, delete and change 
                                    h4 the current system user. As well as add content.
                                    h4 This will be entirely for black box testing and
                                    h4 will not be acessible once the site is live.

                                    h3 current user:
                                    h2 #{currentUser.userName}
                            h2 Current users in database:   
                            h3 this data is being supplied in real-time by the model         

                            each user in userList
                                span.h4 Username: 
                                span.h2= user.userName 
                                - console.log('this is4',user)
                                p(style='text-align:right')
                                    span.h4 Rating:
                                    span.h2= user.rating
                                    a(href="/setuser/#{user._id}")
                                        button(type="button") set as user



                .col-xs-12.col-md-6

                    h1 Add users
                    form.form-horizontal(action="/", method="post", role="form")
                        .form-group
                            label.col-xs-10.col-sm-2.control-label(for="userName") user name
                            .col-xs-12.col-sm-8
                                input#name.form-control(name="userName")
                        .form-group
                            label.col-xs-10.col-sm-2.control-label(for="rating") rating
                            .col-xs-12.col-sm-2
                                select#rating.form-control.input-sm(name="rating")
                                    option 10
                                    option 9
                                    option 8
                                    option 7
                                    option 6
                                    option 5
                                    option 4
                                    option 3
                                    option 2
                                    option 1
                        button.btn.btn-default.pull-right(href="") Add user

                    h1 Add forum posts to current user
                    form.form-horizontal(action="/", method="post", role="form")
                        .form-group
                            label.col-xs-10.col-sm-2.control-label(for="topic") post
                            .col-xs-12.col-sm-8
                                input#name.form-control(name="topic")


                        button.btn.btn-default.pull-right(href="") Add post
```

LAYOUT.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0')
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/forum.css')


  body
    navbar.navbar-defauly.navbar-fixed-top
      .container
        .navbar-header
          a.navbar-brand(href="/home") Create Together
          button.navbar-toggle(type="button", data-toggle="collapse", data-target="#navbar-main")
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
        #navbar-main.navbar-collapse.collapse
          ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
            li
              a(href='/unitplans') Unit planners
            li
              a(href='/forum') Forum
            li
              a(href='/helpme') Help me
            li
              a.selected(href='/') (Admin)
    .col-lg-3
        .panel.panel-primary
                        .panel-heading
                            h2.panel-title User information

                        .panel-body
                            .text-center
                                img(src='/uploads/avatar.jpg', width='200',height=-'300')

                            span.h4 Username
                            center
                            - console.log('this is1',currentUser)
                               span.h2= currentUser.userName

                            h4 Users who recently liked your work
                                center
                                    li.span.h5 mathsGeek82
                                    li.span.h5 algIsBest76
                            h4 Other site related information
                            h4 Rating
                            center
                            - console.log('this is2',currentUser)
                               +ratingText(currentUser.rating)
    .container
      block content 
      footer
        .row
            .col-xs-12
              small footer            

script(src='/javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.js')
script(src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

CONSOLE log

```
adminFire
this is1 { userName: 'no user selected', rating: '10' }
this is2 { userName: 'no user selected', rating: '10' }
this is3 { userName: 'no user selected', rating: '10' }
this is4 { _id: 5bee3c67194ff91a857ba7ed,
  userName: 'me',
  rating: 5,
  __v: 0 }
this is4 { _id: 5bee3e3953ae361b0f62d2a4,
  userName: 'stev',
  rating: 4,
  __v: 0 }
this is4 { _id: 5bee3e91067d181b2fba359a,
  userName: 'bollox',
  rating: 8,
  __v: 0 }
this is4 { _id: 5bee3eb0067d181b2fba359b,
  userName: 'nick',
  rating: 10,
  __v: 0 }
GET / 200 938.186 ms - 4563
GET /bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css 304 15.842 ms - -
GET /bootstrap/css/style.css 304 10.458 ms - -
GET /bootstrap/css/forum.css 304 2.209 ms - -
GET /uploads/avatar.jpg 304 1.848 ms - -
this is1 undefined
GET /javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.js 404 146.950 ms - 3749
TypeError: /Users/smyths1/Desktop/Assign2_restart/Assignment_2_clone_After_ASS2_Complete/app_server/views/layout.jade:43
    41|                             center
    42|                             - console.log('this is1',currentUser)
  > 43|                                span.h2 #{currentUser.userName}
    44|
    45|                             h4 Users who recently liked your work
    46|                                 center
```

EDIT:
Thanks Graham, however it didnt help. I added the return statement:

Here is my res.render code:

```
module.exports.admin = (req, res) => {
    // user find by id then set to active user?
    User.find((err, userList) => {
        console.log('adminFire');
        if (!err) {
            console.log('return adb4');
            res.render('locations-admin', {
                title: 'Create Together',
                userList: userList,            
                currentUser: activeUser
            });
            console.log('return adafter');
            return;
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error in retrieving user list :' + err);
        }
    });
};
```

ANy other thoughts?

EDIT 2: Actually, the problem seems to lie with the res.render code block. I've been playing around with it and it seems that the code runs res.render once successfully (i.e. with the correct variables displayed), but then immediately runs it again with the undefined variables.

Here is my  new console output:

```
adminFire
return adb4
this is1 { userName: 'no user selected', rating: '10' }
this is2 { userName: 'no user selected', rating: '10' }
this is1 undefined
return adafter
GET / 500 2343.440 ms - 3747
TypeError: /Users/smyths1/Desktop/Assign2_restart/Assignment_2_clone_After_ASS2_Complete/app_server/views/layout.jade:42
    40|                             center
    41|                             - console.log('this is1',currentUser)
  > 42|                                span.h2= currentUser.userName
    43|
    44|                             h4 Users who recently liked your work
    45|                                 center
```

EDIT 3: OK, the plot thickens... 
Now, I have commented out ALL of my routes so there is no call to render anything.

However, the program still tries to render the 'layout'. I am totally lost now.

Here is my app.js file:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

// for mongo
require('./app_api/models/db'); 


var indexRouter = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var routesApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'app_server','views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', { layout: false }); 

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api', routesApi);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Latest console log:

```
this is1 undefined
GET / 404 1493.571 ms - 3747
TypeError: /Users/smyths1/Desktop/Assign2_restart/Assignment_2_clone_After_ASS2_Complete/app_server/views/layout.jade:42
    40|                             center
    41|                             - console.log('this is1',currentUser)
  > 42|                                span.h2= currentUser.userName
    43|
```

EDIT 4:
OK, so i see that the layout file is called by res.render as default. If I remove extends layout from my home page it loads without errors. However, if i then add 'extends layout' the problem comes back. It seems that the app is rendering layout by default, then when i try to render the homepage, which extends layout, it tries to render layout again, and the error returns.

I'm pulling my hair out now.

EDIT 5 added layout.jade above:
Thanks for the help Graham but I still cant seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response Graham. However I added a return statement to the res.render and it hasnt helped. Here is my re.render code:

Comment: I can also see that now, if i remove the 'extends layout' at the top of my template file, then the page renders normally. So the problem seems to lie with the layout or the fact I'm extending it.

Comment: I deleted the line you mentioned above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are at least two issues raised here and neither have the complete relevant code pasted in.  This question cannot meet the M, C, or V in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without a complete rewrite.

Comment: Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)